# Two Activities as Launcher. One for smartphone and one for tablet

Tags: android

I want to use two different activities as launcher one for smartphone and other one for tablet. i know that i can put both activities as Launcher in manifest, but how can i invoke them for phone or tablet.

Comment: You might consider looking into one of the newer features of the Android market that allows you to upload different apk's for your application and target them at different devices. Then you could solve this problem at a higher level than the activity.

Comment: thanx tim... i will consider it..

Comment: It's a bit late, but this answer worked ok for me: 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/16542600/689723

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a single activity without layout which will check the android version and start the respective activity each time.

Comment: What do you mean proper? The solution I propose is widely used for such case.

Answer (score 0):

if you use use two different activities as launcher it will put two launcher icon in the device.....you should use different builds for that......